# How to extract the confidence limits of LSMEANS?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, lsmeans

I am using the `oranges` data provided with lsmeans.

```
library(lsmeans)
oranges.rg1<-lm(sales1 ~ price1 + price2 + day + store, data = oranges)
days.lsm <- lsmeans(oranges.rg1, "day")
days_contr.lsm <- contrast(days.lsm, "trt.vs.ctrl", ref = c(5,6))
```

The confidence intervals can be visualized by ploting `plot(contrast(days.lsm, "trt.vs.ctrl", ref = c(5,6)))`, but they are not showed at `days_contr.lsm`

```
> days_contr.lsm
 contrast       estimate       SE df t.ratio p.value
 1 - avg(5,6) -7.8538769 2.194243 23  -3.579  0.0058
 2 - avg(5,6) -6.9234858 2.127341 23  -3.255  0.0125
 3 - avg(5,6)  0.2462789 2.155529 23   0.114  0.9979
 4 - avg(5,6) -4.6760034 2.110761 23  -2.215  0.1184
```

How can I extract the confidence intervals to a data.frame?

```
> days_contr.lsm
 contrast       estimate       SE df t.ratio p.value lower.CL upper.CL
 1 - avg(5,6) -7.8538769 2.194243 23  -3.579  0.0058  ?       ?
 2 - avg(5,6) -6.9234858 2.127341 23  -3.255  0.0125  ?       ?
 3 - avg(5,6)  0.2462789 2.155529 23   0.114  0.9979  ?       ?
 4 - avg(5,6) -4.6760034 2.110761 23  -2.215  0.1184  ?       ?
```

Answer (score 2):

`confint(contrast(days.lsm, "trt.vs.ctrl", ref = c(5,6)))` worked fine

Answer (score 1):

At risk of beating a dead horse, I feel that the main point of the question is getting the confidence intervals, given that what is seen in `days_contr.lsm` is only the *t* ratios and *P* values.

This happened because the default method for summarizing `contrast()` results is to show tests and not CIs, whereas the default method for summarizing `emmeans()` results is to show CIs and not tests. The `infer` argument of `summary.emmGrid()` controls what you see. Thus, you can get both CIs and tests using

```
summary(days_contr.lsm, infer = c(TRUE, TRUE))
```

and this would fill-in the question marks in the OP. The `summary()` result, by the way, is of class `c("summary_emm", "data.frame")`; it is a `data.frame` with a special `print` method that often shows some additional annotations.

There are additional `emmGrid` methods `confint()` and `test()` that run `summary()` with `infer = c(TRUE, FALSE)` and `infer = c(FALSE, TRUE)` respectively (though both have additional capabilities). The `as.data.frame()` method is just `as.data.frame(summary(...))`. For details, see tge help page for `emmeans::summary.emmGrid`.